# TextBlock inside an Expander(in TreeView) not setting Foreground when TreeViewItem is selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, textblock, expander

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TestNode">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <TextBlock Text="Detail Feild 1" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Detail" FontSize="9"/>
            <Expander x:Name="problemExpander" ExpandDirection="Down" IsExpanded="True">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Details:" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Detail" FontSize="9"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Status:" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test Status" FontSize="9"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestNode}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Items}" Width="525" Height="350">

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

the Following 2 textBlocks foregrounds are set properly(they turn white when the TreeViewItem is selected)

```
<TextBlock Text="Detail Feild 1" FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold"/>
<TextBlock Text="Detail" FontSize="9"/>
```

but the foreground in the textblocks inside the expander remain their default color... If i remove the expander, the textblocks work as you(I) would think.

Why is this so?  And is there a way to have it such that the TextBlocks inside the expander will also change their foreground Color?

Comment: The bad answer is that I can bind the Foreground property of the elements inside the Expander to one of the Textblocks Foreground property outside the Expander...  This works, but its not the answer (nor the understanding as to WHY this behavior occurs) that I was looking for

                    <TextBlock Text="Detail" x:Name="outerTextBlock"/>
                    <Expander x:Name="problemExpander" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Details:" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=outerTextBlock, Path=Foreground}"/>

Comment: Which color are you talking about? I dont see you setting the foreground color anywhere in the code you showed us? And I did site search for foreground lol

Comment: You don't need to set the foreground color, it is black implicitly.  If the textblock is inside of something that is selected the foreground turns white...??? put the xaml in and create something for the Items binding, you'll see exactly what happens....derp

Comment: Ok, I see the picture now clearer. I must have misread that in first place. The value inheritance is not working and I know why or better said I know how you could fix this easly. Just, I dont feel like answering this or helping you out any futher because of that derp part. Take care, have fun.